# Google Play Store application in phone is not detecting available application update for my application that is published on Play

Tags: android, publish

I published a new version of my application on Google Play store and it was available to be downloaded by users after couple of hours. But the problem is with the users who already have the older version of the application. Google play does not show update option for all those users. Any suggestion what could be the reason? Just to mention versionCode(1170 earlier it was 1095) and versionName (1.6.1 earlier it was 1.5) both are higher than the previous published version.

Comment: Thank God!!! you have uploaded it. It didn't allow me to update!!!!!!!!

Comment: i think they are not tick automatic update check box when they installed application.

Comment: yeah but in my own phone If I go to that application, I dont see "update" option instead i see "open" option.

Comment: Scroll Down it above comments . .

Comment: when I go to my apps in Play store I can see two tabs "Installed"  and "All". Whats the criteria that some apps are under installed not all the apps that I downloaded from Play?

Comment: @ChiragRaval I can see the latest version of the application that I lately published (i.e. 1.6.1) in the description, but not the update button.

Comment: it automatic update in device. .

Comment: automatic update checkbox is checked in this scenario.

Comment: I tried "Uninstall updates" to Google Play Store application by going into Settings->Applications->Manage applications. By doing this i was moved back to Market application and in there I can see that an update is available to my application, but once that Market application is updated to Play I can't see update to my application. Any guesses whats going wrong for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a bug in Google Play and now they have fixed it and now users of my application can see that there is new updated version available.